# Excel formula to automatically add cell values from one column corresponding to a values from another cell

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

in column A of my spreadsheet, I want to enter a country (via a drop-down list of countries defined in e.g. L1:L120).  In column B, I want to automatically have the corresponding 3-digit country code (defined in e.g. M1:M120) appear once country in column A is entered.

I have meanwhile found out that I probably need to use VLOOKUP, but ccaanot figure out the exact way to move forward.
Any advise or suggestions please?

Comment: If you already knew (or suspected) that `VLOOKUP` would do this, and if you have tried to use it, you should *say those things in the question.*

Answer (score 0):

Use vlookup function to lookup the country code

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This is really more of a hint than a solution.  As-is, it would be more appropriate as a comment, which requires a little more rep.  Can you expand this with a "how to" example?

Comment: Indeed, I was as far as trying vlookup as well, only the exact way to do it is what I am looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. One is using an IF statement, however, if your country list is large the IF statement would become too large to use, so I will focus on [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1).

1. Add a sheet to your workbook called CountryCodes
2. In Column A, list all of your countries.
3. In Column B, list the corresponding country code for each country
4. In your original worksheet, in Column B-Row 2, enter this formula: `=VLOOKUP(B2,CountryCodes,2,FALSE)`
5. Copy the formula across all rows in your data set.

If Column A is empty, Column B will show #N/A. If Column A has a country selected, Column B should automatically update to show the code.

NOTE: The countries listed in your CountryCodes worksheet must match *exactly* with the countries in your drop-down list.

[image: Example]